# How to import multiple rows from excel in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I want to import multiple rows of an excel file into database in laravel.

**My code in imports:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\LeadDetails;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class LeadsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $rows)
    {
        // dd($rows);
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
                return new LeadDetails([
                    // "lead_id" => $lead_id,
                    "full_name" => $row['name'],
                    "student_email" => $row['email'],
                    "phone_number" => $row['contact'],
                    "work_location" => $row['work_location'],
                    "phone_number" => $row['contact'],
                    "lead_apply_date" => $row['date'],
                    "lead_remarks" => $row['remark'],
                ]);
        }
    }
}
```

**controller function:**

```
public function uploadLeadExcel(Request $request)
    {
        Excel::import(new LeadsImport, $request->file);
        return response()->json([
            'message'=>'success',
            'status'=>201
        ]);
    }
```

When hitting from postman an error appears telling 'undefined offset name in file . Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok now its working. I have installed laravel excel according to documentation and used

```
class LeadsImport implements ToCollection
```

Answer (score 0):

Because $row doesn't have a key 'name'. Try:

```
return new LeadDetails([
    // "lead_id" => $lead_id,
    "full_name" => $row['name'] ?? '',
    "student_email" => $row['email'] ?? '',
    "phone_number" => $row['contact'] ?? '',
    "work_location" => $row['work_location'] ?? '',
    "phone_number" => $row['contact'] ?? '',
    "lead_apply_date" => $row['date'] ?? '',
    "lead_remarks" => $row['remark'] ?? '',
]);
```

You should modify lead_id column of the table to auto increment

Comment: Another error is appearing "Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'lead_details_lead_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `lead_details` (`full_name`, `student_email`, `phone_number`, `work_location`, `lead_apply_date`, `lead_remarks`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , , , 2023-04-02 07:51:59, 2023-04-02 07:51:59))"

Comment: Without loop with single row,its working . But not with multiple

Comment: You should modify lead_id column of the table to auto increment

Comment: $row variables are not getting any value. What can be the cause ?

Comment: Can you dd($rows ) and display it in your question?